# Int32 computation difference between Java and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, overflow, int32

I need to rewrite some legacy Java code performing arithmetic transformations from Java to TypeScript/JavaScript. The problem is the legacy code uses the `int` Java type (signed 32-bits) and relies on overflows. I almost got what I want using Int32Array in JavaScript, but I still have a difference I can't explain. Look below.

Java:

```java
int current = -1599751945;
int next = current * 0x08088405 + 1;
System.out.println("next = " + next);
```

Output: next = **374601940**

Javascript:

```js
const a = new Int32Array(4)

a[0] = -1599751945
a[1] = 0x08088405
a[2] = 1
a[3] = a[0]*a[1] + a[2]

console.log('a[3] = ' + a[3])
```

Output: a[3] = **374601952**

Can someone explain the difference? And how can I get same result in JavaScript? I tried shift operations, coerce with |0, methods to convert etc., but best result is the one above.

Comment: Related question that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30678303/5133585

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Math.imul() in JavaScript. That should produce the correct result.

```
const a = new Int32Array(4)

a[0] = -1599751945
a[1] = 0x08088405
a[2] = 1
a[3] = Math.imul(a[0], a[1]) + a[2]

console.log('a[3] = ' + a[3])
```

Additional details as to why can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21865422/14359869).

Answer (score 1):

I can't provide a definitive answer as to exactly why you get these exact numbers; but consider that all numbers in JS are doubles.

So, whereas `current * 0x08088405` is done using integer arithmetic in Java, `a[0]*a[1]` is done using double arithmetic in JS, so these intermediate results are different; and the limited precision of a double means that adding 1 to that doesn't actually change the value:

```
console.log(a[0]*a[1]) => -215607868985706270
console.log(a[0]*a[1] + a[2]) => = -215607868985706270
```

Compare this to Java, where integer arithmetic is used:

```
int[] a = { -1599751945, 0x08088405, 1};
System.out.println(a[0]*a[1])          => 374601939
System.out.println(a[0]*a[1] + a[2])   => 374601940
```

If we make Java do this in double arithmetic:

```
double[] a = { -1599751945, 0x08088405, 1};
System.out.println(a[0]*a[1]);         => -2.15607868985706272E17
System.out.println(a[0]*a[1] + a[2]);  => -2.15607868985706272E17
```

You can see that this is *almost* the same, but differs in the least significant digit:

```
-215607868985706270  // JS
-215607868985706272  // Java
```

I don't know why there is such a difference here.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explaination !

Answer (score 0):

Floating point numbers only support precision up to a specific number of digits. JavaScript promotes numbers larger than 32 bits to floating point numbers.

Java is "more correct" here.

```js
// -215607868985706285 is the 64 bit result of your multiplication
console.log(-215607868985706285); // will print -215607868985706285
```

See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) for a general discussion of this topic.